# Panotour Pro 2 - Adding KML in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been working with the Google Maps API v3 in Panotour for a few days now and had been adding my own KML layers to my Panotour Maps. I had it working yesterday but today it seems to have been broken somehow.

To add my own KML layers I am basically just adding a piece of script to my project build under "\graphics\KolorMap\lib\mxn.googlev3.core".

This is the chunk of code I was piecing into the googlev3.core file. Its the KML sample from the developers website. I wanted to get it working before adding my own custom stuff.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

I have added a link to the mxn.googlev3.core. If anyone knows where I need to put my code or if I need to add anything that would be much appreciated.

[mxn.googlev3.core](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hfYfzc5XaxUUItRHpDdjZNNFk/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was able to figure this out on my own folks. Thanks to anyone who had a look at this.

Comment: Are you going to share the issue/solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are still some bugs that I am sorting through and I may still need some help with them.

Below is the code excerpt from the mxn.googlev3.core file.  The code is from Line 1 to about Line 140. I forget where exactly because I have added my own code.

```
mxn.register('googlev3', {

Mapstraction: {

init: function(element, api){
    var me = this;

    if (typeof google.maps.Map === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(api + ' map script not imported');
    }

    // by default add road map and no controls
    var myOptions = {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: null,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: null,
        panControl: false,
        panControlOptions: null,
        scaleControl: false,
        scaleControlOptions: null,
        scrollwheel: true,
        draggable: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    };

    // Background color can only be set at construction
    // To provide some control, adopt any explicit element style
    var backgroundColor = null;
    if ( element.currentStyle ) {
        backgroundColor = element.currentStyle['background-color'];
    }
    else if ( window.getComputedStyle ) {
        backgroundColor = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
    }
    // Only set the background if a style has been explicitly set, ruling out the "transparent" default
    if ( backgroundColor && 'transparent' !== backgroundColor ) {
        myOptions.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    // find controls
    if (!this.addControlsArgs && loadoptions.addControlsArgs) {
        this.addControlsArgs = loadoptions.addControlsArgs;
    }
    if (this.addControlsArgs) {
        if (this.addControlsArgs.zoom) {
            myOptions.zoomControl = true;
            if (this.addControlsArgs.zoom == 'small') {
                myOptions.zoomControlOptions = {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT};
            }
            if (this.addControlsArgs.zoom == 'large') {
                myOptions.zoomControlOptions = {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT};
            }
        }
        if (this.addControlsArgs.scale) {
            myOptions.scaleControl = true;
            myOptions.scaleControlOptions = {style:google.maps.ScaleControlStyle.DEFAULT,position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT};
        }
        if (this.addControlsArgs.pan) {
            myOptions.panControl = true;
            myOptions.panControlOptions = {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT};
        }
        if (this.addControlsArgs.map_type) {
            myOptions.mapTypeControl = true;
            myOptions.mapTypeControlOptions = {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT};
        }
        if (this.addControlsArgs.overview) {
            myOptions.overviewMapControl = true;
            myOptions.overviewMapControlOptions = {opened: true};
        }
    }

    // Enable the visual refresh
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, myOptions);

    var fireOnNextIdle = [];

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        var fireListCount = fireOnNextIdle.length;
        if (fireListCount > 0) {
            var fireList = fireOnNextIdle.splice(0, fireListCount);
            var handler;
            while((handler = fireList.shift())){
                handler();
            }
        }
    });

    // deal with click
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(location){
        me.click.fire({'location': 
            new mxn.LatLonPoint(location.latLng.lat(),location.latLng.lng())
        });
    });

    // deal with zoom change
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
        // zoom_changed fires before the zooming has finished so we 
        // wait for the next idle event before firing our changezoom
        // so that method calls report the correct values
        fireOnNextIdle.push(function() {
            me.changeZoom.fire();
        });
    });

    // deal with map movement
    var is_dragging = false;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
        is_dragging = true;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(){
        me.moveendHandler(me);
        me.endPan.fire();
        is_dragging = false; 
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        me.endPan.fire();
    });

    // deal with initial tile loading
    var loadListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
        me.load.fire();
        google.maps.event.removeListener( loadListener );
        if (!is_dragging) {
            fireOnNextIdle.push(function() {
                me.endPan.fire();
            });
        }
    });

    this.maps[api] = map;
    this.loaded[api] = true;

 // THIS IS THE KML CODE THAT YOU NEED TO INSERT -START

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'Insert your kml here link here'
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

 //END KML CODE SECTION

},
```

The "Insert your kml link here" is where you put your kml url link.

For some reason the attributes stop displaying at intermittent times. They will work and then I will go to click on a feature again to view the attributes and nothing. This is one of the bugs. I am also messing around with document links within the kml feature attribute tables. As I get deeper into this this Panoramic program is becoming more of a GIS program.

If anyone has any other ideas about this please feel free to make suggestions.

Comment: A large part of it was figuring out exactly where to put my kml code. But I still am having issues with the attributes not displaying at certain times.